# Nvidia GeForce 210 compute issue on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gpu, ubuntu-18.04, nvidia

I am using ubuntu 18.04 (I have dual booted windows with ubuntu 18.04).

```
nvidia-smi
```

This is the output I got when I ran the above command on my ubuntu(18.04) terminal:

```
Fri Oct  9 09:33:56 2020       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 340.108    Driver Version: 340.108        |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 210         Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 35%   52C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    368MiB /  1023MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Before that, I followed these steps to install required driver on my system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo shutdown -r now
```

When I tried to run [Geekbench5](https://www.geekbench.com/) compute benchmark test, the output stopped when it was running Histogram Equalization. This is the output when I ran this `./geekbench5 --compute OpenCL` in the folder where I extracted geekbench5:

```
[1009/092949:FATAL:src/halogen/cuda/cuda_library.cpp(1481)] Failed to load 

cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1: undefined symbol: cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain
[1009/092949:FATAL:src/halogen/cuda/cuda_library.cpp(1481)] Failed to load cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1: undefined symbol: cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain
Geekbench 5.2.4 Tryout : https://www.geekbench.com/

Geekbench 5 is in tryout mode.

Geekbench 5 requires an active Internet connection when in tryout mode, and 
automatically uploads test results to the Geekbench Browser. Other features 
are unavailable in tryout mode.

Buy a Geekbench 5 license to enable offline use and remove the limitations of 
tryout mode.

If you would like to purchase Geekbench you can do so online:

  https://store.primatelabs.com/v5

If you have already purchased Geekbench, enter your email address and license 
key from your email receipt with the following command line:

  ./geekbench5 -r <email address> <license key>

  Running Gathering system information
System Information
  Operating System              Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS 4.15.0-118-generic x86_64
  Model                         To be filled by O.E.M. To be filled by O.E.M.
  Motherboard                   O.E.M Intel H81
  BIOS                          American Megatrends Inc. 4.6.5

Processor Information
  Name                          Intel Core i5-4460
  Topology                      1 Processor, 4 Cores
  Identifier                    GenuineIntel Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3
  Base Frequency                3.20 GHz
  L1 Instruction Cache          32.0 KB x 2
  L1 Data Cache                 32.0 KB x 2
  L2 Cache                      256 KB x 2
  L3 Cache                      6.00 MB

Memory Information
  Size                          7.75 GB

OpenCL Information
  Platform Vendor               NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Name                 NVIDIA CUDA
  Device Vendor                 NVIDIA Corporation
  Device Name                   GeForce 210
  Device Driver Version         340.108
  Maximum Frequency             1.23 GHz
  Compute Units                 2
  Device Memory                 1024 MB


OpenCL
  Running Sobel
  Running Canny
  Running Stereo Matching
  Running Histogram Equalization
[1009/093329:ERROR:src/interface/console/consolemain.cpp(808)] Geekbench encountered an internal error and cannot continue. Please contact support@primatelabs.com for assistance.

Internal error message: clCreateImage returned -40.
```

Also, when I tried running the geekbench5 compute benchmark test on windows 10(same machine, on GUI), it paused running at Histogram equalization.

I am not getting any idea why this is happening.Is anything really wrong with my GPU or driver or anything else?
 I tried to search online, installed the driver again,rebooted the system, but the results are same. Can someone please help?

Comment: I just want to know why is my question down-voted. Is it obsolete or unclear? I am new to this platform and tried to search for an answer before posting this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your driver installation is fine, but your GPU is 11 years old and does not support some of the more recent features of the OpenCL standard. The geekbench error message `-40` means that the image size geekbench uses for one of its benchmarks is not supported by your GPU. This causes the benchmark to crash. Maybe an older version of geekbench still works.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try the test with an older version of geekbench. Also, if you don't mind can you suggest some ways to interpret the error messages?

Comment: Here is the list of OpenCL error codes: https://streamhpc.com/blog/2013-04-28/opencl-error-codes/ Some of them are a bit inconclusive however and have a different cause than officially stated.